# How can I run multiple DDL statements from a recordset loop?

Tags: ms-access, ddl

Hopefully an easy one- for obvious reasons, I would like to rename several thousand field names to remove spaces and special characters across hundreds of tables.  I put all the edits into a simple table, and generated the DDL statement for each field via a query.

Such as:

currentdb.TableDefs("tblA").Fields("Bad Field / Name - why_do_this").Name = "GoodFieldName"

I can run the DDL statement in the immediate window, no problem.  But a dozen variations on trying to run this in a vba module via looping trough a recordset have failed.

If I try DoCmd.RunSQL (rs(0)) and get an error:

Run-time error '3129', Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE','INSERT','PROCEDURE','SELECT', OR 'UPDATE'.

(I did verify rs(0) contains the DDL text).

Is there a way to run a DDL string from a recordset? Or do I need to build that string inside the VBA module?  Thanks!!!

Edit:  I gave up on Plan A.  This code below worked.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateFieldName_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database, tdf As DAO.TableDef
   
Set db = CurrentDb

    
    strSQL = "select TableName,FieldName,SQLFieldName from qryRemote_qryFieldsSQLOutput where TableName='" & Me.cmbTableName & "' and SQLFieldName is not null"
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    With rs
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
            While (Not .EOF)
                    If VerifyFieldExists(rs("FieldName"), rs("TableName")) Then
                        Set tdf = db.TableDefs(rs("TableName"))
                        tdf(rs("FieldName")).Name = rs("SQLFieldName")
                    End If
                    
            .MoveNext
            Wend
        End If
    End With
    
   
   Set tdf = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I would certainly use VBA and DAO for this. Simple to write, and easy to debug.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention if you saved the SQL DDL "alter table" as queries, or that you have some text file or list of SQL commands that exists some place?

However, you can certainly have a text file of DDL commands, or a table of DDL commands, or even a bunch of saved queries as DDL commands.

All of the above are viable choices.

However, if we have a table say like this:

[image]

Then just build a form - continues or whatever, and we have this:

[image]

So, we can thus type in commands for each operation we want. And note in above, we terminate each command with a ";".

So, code to process the above (the above button code) is this:

```
Private Sub cmdSQL_Click()

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False ' save current reocrd
    
    
    Dim rstSQL      As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim SQLArray()  As String
    Dim vSQLrun     As Variant
        
    
    Set rstSQL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSQL ORDER BY ID")
        
    Do While rstSQL.EOF = False
        SQLArray = Split(rstSQL!SQL, ";")
        
        ' Now execute each SQL command in this row
        For Each vSQLrun In SQLArray
           CurrentDb.Execute vSQLrun, dbFailOnError
           'Debug.Print vSQLrun
        Next
    
        rstSQL.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "done"
    
End Sub
```

And note that to re-name a column you really can't use MS-Access DDL's commands. You have to create the new column, copy the data, drop the older column, and potentially add an index.

If that column is part of a relationship, then the above is not really a viable suggestion.

However, for some types of altering of a database, the above approach can be rather valuable.

However, due to the issue of indexing, and relationships (which will break with above code), then we could simply have a table of changes, and NOT use SQL DDL' commands, but use the DAO object model, and that will allow us to change the column name, but not have to copy nor create a new column.

However, the above does show how it is rather easy to execute multiple commands. As noted, we could also read line by line from a text file, and again a similar approach to above would allow one to "process" a text file of SQL scripting commands). So, above is a SQL script running solution.

The MS-access data engine can't execute multiple SQL commands at once, but if you split based on ";", then you achieve this ability with a small amount of VBA code.

While using DDL's commands I think is great for adding new columns?

For re-naming, then using DAO is a far better choice.

So, I suggest a table with these columns:

[image]

Now, again, we process each row, say like this:

```
Sub ChangeColumns()

    Dim rstChanges      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rtabledef       As DAO.TableDef
    Dim db              As DAO.Database
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
                   
    Set rstChanges = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblRenameColumns ORDER BY ID")
            
    Do While rstChanges.EOF = False
    
        Set rtabledef = db.TableDefs(rstChanges!TableName)
        Call MyColRename(rtabledef, rstChanges!OldColumn, rstChanges!NewColumn)
        ' db.TableDefs.Refresh ' optional - do at end of processing
      
        rstChanges.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstChanges.Close
    

End Sub


Sub MyColRename(ByRef rtabledef As DAO.TableDef, sOldCol As String, sNewCol As String)


    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    
    For Each fld In rtabledef.Fields
        
        If fld.Name = sOldCol Then
            fld.Name = sNewCol
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

So, for new columns, I suggest the first example (using SQL DDL commands).

However, using the DAO object model is a far better choice to rename existing columns as above shows. No copy of data is required, no re-indexing, and in fact even relationships will remain intact.

However, existing SQL commands in the application, and existing forms, and VBA code all will of course require updates to reflect the new column name.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful background and a solution.   Good point about indexes and relationships that would break- In my particular case there are none to worry about (should have noted that).  I edited my question with a solution.  DDL worked for me in the end but your DAO approach is more broadly applicable.